# getItemSummaries1, containerType - investment -> empty

Tags: c#, yodlee

I'm trying to get holdings list for the client, using test users sbMemrixtrema #

use the instructions http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation/Aggregation_Services/Holding

Result function dataService.getItemSummaries1 = null 
dataService.getItemSummaries = returns some data cards and banks. 
But I need information on investment holdings.

How to fill in the data for the test client? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to link an investment account first and then you can get data around investment holdings. You can use the [dummy account generator](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Indy_FinApp_Knowledgebase/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator) which yodlee provides for dummy accounts.

Steps which you can take to add an investment account -

1. Go to "My Profile" page and then to "Developer Info".
2. Click the "FastLink" link by the test user.
3. Use the fastLink floater to add a DagSite account.

Then you can use the DataService APIs to get the holding details.